# Regex for Nested Quotes from bbcode

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, nested

I've looked all over the place for a regex that would work for this in C# but can't get anything. I found a lot for PHP but not sure on how to convert it over to C#. So what I'm trying to do is simply create a regex that recursively matches the bbcode for a quote and then changes it to HTML. Here's an example:

```
[quote="bob"]I can't believe that you said this: [quote="joe"]I love lamp.
[/quote] That's hilarious![/quote]
```

That should turn into:

```
<fieldset class="bbquote"><legend>bob</legend>I can't believe that you said 
this: <fieldset class="bbquote"><legend>joe</legend>I love lamp.</fieldset> 
That's hilarious!</fieldset>
```

All of the regex expressions I have tried have failed miserably.

Comment: " I found a lot for PHP but not sure on how to convert it over to C#" - a regex is pretty much a regex (with a few small variations)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Using the PHP ones in the C# code did not work. And I wasn't really including a tag, but trying to emphasize that it's in C# so that it wouldn't be confusing. Sorry for the misunderstanding..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to do that recursively or to match the corresponding start and end of a quote - at last, just the same number of starts and ends must have been replaced. This can be accomplished for any nesting with e. g.:

```
void Main()
{
    String s = "[quote=\"bob\"]I can't believe that you said this: [quote=\"joe\"]I love lamp.[/quote] That's hilarious![/quote]";
    Regex r = new Regex(@"\[quote=""(\w+)""\](.*?)\[/quote]");
    while (r.Match(s).Success)
        s = r.Replace(s, "<fieldset class=\"bbquote\"><legend>$1</legend>$2</fieldset>");
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        String sample = "[quote=\"bob\"]I can't believe that you said this: [quote=\"joe\"]I love lamp.[/quote] That's hilarious![/quote]";
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?:(?:\[quote="")(\w+)(?:""\])?([^\[]+))(?:(?:\[quote="")(\w+)(?:""\])?([^\[]+))(?:[^\]]+\]\s)([^\[]+)(?:\[\/quote\])");

        Match match = regex.Match(sample);

        if (match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(sample,"<fieldset class=\"bbquote\"><legend>$1</legend>$2<fieldset class=\"bbquote\"><legend>$3</legend>$4</fieldset>$5</fieldset>"));
        }
    }
}
```

it captures 5 groups:

- $1 bob
- $2 I can't believe that you said this:
- $3 joe
- $4 I love lamp.
- $5 That's hilarious!

which you can replace to get:

```
<fieldset class="bbquote"><legend>bob</legend>I can't believe that you said this: <fieldset class="bbquote"><legend>joe</legend>I love lamp.</fieldset>That's hilarious!</fieldset>
```

Comment: Although it looks like that works, I'm trying to not worry about knowing the exact number of recursive calls a quote takes on. So if a person has a single quote (no recursive calls), that's easy. But the same regular expression should be able to determine whether there's two or more recursive calls. So a triple quoted discussion would be just as easy to do. I got it working with simple bbcodes like underlining, bold text, etc. (which only require saving one group). But saving two groups and recursively going down is where I'm having trouble. Until someone has that answer, I'll use this. Thanks